# What does this shell command mean "exec 3>&1 > >(logger -t "OKOK")"

Tags: linux, bash

I've found the following bash command in some source code.

```
exec 3>&1 > >(logger -t "OKOK")
```

What does it exactly mean?

As far as I know, it redirects those log to the syslog.

However, What is `3>&1`?

I have never seen a file descriptor of 3 before.

Comment: It redirects fd 3 to fd 1 then redirects that to logger. What exactly is your question, since you seem to understand the redirects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

unusual indeed, but it does exist:

> Each open file gets assigned a file descriptor. The file descriptors for stdin, stdout, and stderr are 0, 1, and 2, respectively. **For opening additional files, there remain descriptors 3 to 9**. It is sometimes useful to assign one of these additional file descriptors to stdin, stdout, or stderr as a temporary duplicate link. This simplifies restoration to normal after complex redirection and reshuffling

Find out more on the [IO redirection page](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

Comment: so, for some command line application, it will assign some output to a specific descriptor?

Comment: cause in that bash, i can't find any assignment to file desciptor 3.

Answer (score 0):

From this line on, everything printed to STDOUT will be processed by `logger`. The original STDOUT has been saved in fd3, so you can later (if needed) restore the normal STDOUT. See [Advanced BASH Scripting Guide](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/x13082.html) for details.

Comment: would some command line application like to save the original stdout to fd3 instead of 1?

Comment: Yes, because 1 is needed to be sent to the logger.